# More elegant iterating over several bash arrays in parallel

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm working on a script that chews on some data it sucks in from a CSV file.  I've already read the data into several arrays (one for each column in the file); I now need to actually work with all of the data in sequence.

Currently, I am doing this:

```
# Read in the data:
declare -a DATACOL1 DATACOL2 RAWDATA
RAWDATA=($( sed '1d' /path/to/data.csv )) # Remove the header line
for line in ${RAWDATA[@]}; do
   declare -a LINEDATA LINE
   LINE=$( echo "$line" | sed 's/,/ /g' )
   for field in LINE; do
       LINEDATA+=("${field}")
   done
   DATACOL1+=(${LINEDATA[0]})
   DATACOL2+=(${LINEDATA[1]})
done


# Work on the data:
for i in $( seq 0 $[${#DATACOL1[@]}-1}; do
   stuff and things with ${DATACOL1[i]} and ${DATACOL2[i]}
done
```

My (quite possibly interrelated) questions are twofold:

- Is there a more elegant way to later work in the data than `for i in $( seq 0 $[${#DATACOL1[@]}-1}` for iterating over them?  It works, but is ugly.
- Is there a more elegant way to suck in the CSV data?

This is on bash 3, so I do not have associative arrays.

Comment: Can we write it in perl?  (typo: seed -> sed)

Comment: This would probably be a _lot_ easier to do in perl/python, but it's preferred in this instance to stick with bash, as it's one cog in a fairly extensive bash Rube Goldberg machine, and I'd just as soon keep all the cogs speaking the same language.

Comment: Your method of reading the file will break if there is any whitespace.

Comment: I know; the CSV file is maintained separately but in-house and we ensure there is no whitespace.

Comment: there's nothing *elegant* about shell arrays. they are large, ponderous, and wasteful.

Comment: I didn't say _elegant_, I said _more elegant_; it's a quality I'm striving for even if it can't actually be reached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write:

```
mapfile -t rawdata < <(sed 1d /path/to/data.csv)
datacol1=()
datacol2=()

for line in "${rawdata[@]}"; do
    IFS=, read -ra fields <<< "$line"
    datacol1+=( "${fields[0]}" )
    datacol2+=( "${fields[1]}" )
done

for ((i=0; i < "${#datacol1[@]}"; i++)); do
    stuff with "${datacol1[i]}" and "${datacol2[i]}"
done
```

- use `mapfile` to read the lines of a file into an array
- use `IFS` and `read` to read comma-separated fields from a line

  - will break with any commas inside quoted strings: **use a real CSV parser**.
- use the C-like form of `for` to avoid calling out to seq

Of course, you don't need the 2nd loop or the datacol* variables

```
for line in "${rawdata[@]}"; do
    IFS=, read -a fields <<< "$line"
    stuff with "${fields[0]}" and "${fields[1]}"
done
```

---

On bash 3 you won't have `mapfile`, so use a while-loop

```
datacol1=()
datacol2=()
while IFS=, read -ra fields; do
    datacol1+=("${fields[0]}")
    datacol2+=("${fields[1]}")
done < <(sed 1d /path/to/data.csv)
```

Comment: Thanks, mucking about with `IFS` is obvious in retrospect and is exactly the answer I needed.  And the for loop is more verbose, but a lit less ugly than `seq 0 $[${#DATACOL1[@]}-1}`.  Thanks for both.

Comment: This doesn't seem to want to run in parallel for me, the last example.